# rpc_address and broadcast_rpc address for cassandra.yaml for Datastax OpsCenter

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

So I have a single node cassandra running on an AWS machine which also has the OpsCenter installed. I'm trying to manage it with OpsCenter GUI from a windows machine (which is in the same private network as the cassandra node)however I keep getting the following error

"No HTTP communication to the agent"

Opscenter logs show the following information -

2017-02-19 18:08:17,622 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Node 172.18.51.175 changed its mode to normal (MainThread)
2017-02-19 18:08:17,773 [Test_Cluster]  INFO: Using 1.2.3.4 as the RPC address for node 172.18.51.175 (MainThread)
2017-02-19 18:09:12,046 [Test_Cluster]  WARN: These nodes reported this message, Nodes: ['172.18.51.175'] Message: HTTP request http://1.2.3.4:61621/connection-status? failed: User timeout caused connection failure. (MainThread)
2017-02-19 18:10:12,045 [Test_Cluster]  WARN: These nodes reported this message, Nodes: ['172.18.51.175'] Message: HTTP request http://1.2.3.4:61621/connection-status? failed: User timeout caused connection failure. (MainThread)
2017-02-19 18:11:12,046 [Test_Cluster]  WARN: These nodes reported this message, Nodes: ['172.18.51.175'] Message: HTTP request http://1.2.3.4:61621/connection-status? failed: IPv4Address(TCP, '1.2.3.4', 61621) (MainThread)
2017-02-19 18:12:12,045 [Test_Cluster]  WARN: These nodes reported this message, Nodes: ['172.18.51.175'] Message: HTTP request http://1.2.3.4:61621/connection-status? failed: IPv4Address(TCP, '1.2.3.4', 61621) (MainThread)
2017-02-19 18:13:12,433 [Test_Cluster]  WARN: These nodes reported this message, Nodes: ['172.18.51.175'] Message: HTTP request http://1.2.3.4:61621/connection-status? failed: IPv4Address(TCP, '1.2.3.4', 61621) (MainThread)
2017-02-19 18:14:12,045 [Test_Cluster]  WARN: These nodes reported this message, Nodes: ['172.18.51.175'] Message: HTTP request http://1.2.3.4:61621/connection-status? failed: IPv4Address(TCP, '1.2.3.4', 61621) (MainThread)
2017-02-19 18:15:12,045 [Test_Cluster]  WARN: These nodes reported this message, Nodes: ['172.18.51.175'] Message: HTTP request http://1.2.3.4:61621/connection-status? failed: User timeout caused connection failure. (MainThread)
2017-02-19 18:16:12,044 [Test_Cluster]  WARN: These nodes reported this message, Nodes: ['172.18.51.175'] Message: HTTP request http://1.2.3.4:61621/connection-status? failed: IPv4Address(TCP, '1.2.3.4', 61621) (MainThread)
2017-02-19 18:17:12,044 [Test_Cluster]  WARN: These nodes reported this message, Nodes: ['172.18.51.175'] Message: HTTP request http://1.2.3.4:61621/connection-status? failed: IPv4Address(TCP, '1.2.3.4', 61621) (MainThread)
2017-02-19 18:18:12,045 [Test_Cluster]  WARN: These nodes reported this message, Nodes: ['172.18.51.175'] Message: HTTP request http://1.2.3.4:61621/connection-status? failed: IPv4Address(TCP, '1.2.3.4', 61621) (MainThread)

So I guess my cassandra.yaml file needs some change ?

Currently I have set listen_address as private IP of my node

my rpc_address is 0.0.0.0

and my broadcast_rpc_address is set as 1.2.3.4

Which is how the datastax doc recommended.

I tried setting the rpc_address and broadcast_rpc_address to the node's private IP and it failed in that scenario as well.

netstat --listen shows the below line for the port 61621 and 61620

tcp6       0      0 [::]:61620              [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:61621              [::]:*                  LISTEN

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or how to set these parameters in cassandra.yaml for it to work with Opscenter.

Note : I seem to be having issues only with OpsCenter with the above config. Cassandra services start up fine and my web application is connecting to the cluster using the datastax driver. Any one have comments on what might be going wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my rpc_address is 0.0.0.0
>
> and my broadcast_rpc_address is set as 1.2.3.4

That is your mistake, change the rpc_address to the local IP --> 172.18.51.175 [if this is the nodes IP]

Check in cassandra.yaml file that the listen_address is also set to --> 172.18.51.175